# Как передать список продуктов из JS в PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

у меня есть форма и список продуктов. Я передаю форму с помощью PHPMailer на почту, но не совсем понимаю как мне передать список заказанных продуктов. Список продуктов подгружается на страницу из localStorage. Могу ли я как-то передать данные из локального хранилища в PHP?

Это JS:

```
            e.preventDefault();
            const formAction = form.getAttribute('action') ? form.getAttribute('action').trim() : '#';
            const formMethod = form.getAttribute('method') ? form.getAttribute('method').trim() : 'GET';
            const formData = new FormData(form);
            
            form.classList.add('_sending');
            const response = await fetch(formAction, {
                method: formMethod,
                body: {
                    'formData': formData
                }
            })
```

Это одна карточка продукта, их может быть много (в localStorage хранится такая же HTML разметка):

```
<li data-cart-pid="2-750" class="cart-header__item item-cart">
        <a href="" class="item-cart__image _ibg">
            <img src="img/products/product.png" alt="Мед">
        </a>
        <div class="item-cart__content">
            <div class="item-cart__info">
                <a href="" class="item-cart__title">
                    <span class="item-cart__name">Мед</span>,
                    <span class="item-cart__weigh">750г</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cart__quantity">
                <button type="button" class="item-cart__button item-cart__button_minus">-</button>
                <div class="item-cart__input">
                    <span>4</span>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="item-cart__button item-cart__button_plus">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-cart__control">
            <div class="item-cart__price">
                <span>600</span>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cart__delete">
                <span>
                
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто читаете из localStorage свои данные по ключу (по которому они туда записаны) https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage и <strike>отправляете в body отдельным параметром</strike>

```
const response = await fetch(formAction, {
                method: formMethod,
                body: {
                    'formData': formData,
                    'storage': <your-storage-data>
                }
            })
```

а на бэке считываете этот параметр и встраиваете в текст письма

Upd:
Попробуйте тогда в саму formData запушить код как доп.поле

```
const formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('storage', <your-storage-data>);
            
            const response = await fetch(formAction, {
                method: formMethod,
                body: formData
            })
```

Comment: Принимается также как и input с помощью $_POST? Я пробовал что-то подобное, но у меня почему-то все ломалось и не отправлялась даже форма

Comment: Ясно, ограничение fetch. Попробуйте тогда в саму formData запушить код как доп.поле https://plnkr.co/edit/m0fkC9qGU6ZvmwEU?preview

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: Такой вопрос, а как теперь принять эти данные? Обычный способ $_POST видимо не работает

Comment: Чуть подправил код, попробуйте `body: formData` без дополнительной обертки, тогда на сервере в $_POST будут переданные параметры из formData. Почему с оберткой не работает, я понять не могу пока

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался. Уже работает.

Comment: Поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку на моем ответе, если он Вам помог.